# Next.js page is there a way to prevent reloads every time I focus on the Browser tab

Tags: next.js

I am developing my first Next.js application and have deployed my first beta version.

I notice that on the browser, if I move to another tab and revisit on the tab containing the Next js app, it reloads the page. This includes reloading any API based data etc.

Is there some setting to avoid this?

Thanks.